# Flutter | How to design bottom tab like below image

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

Here, I want to design the bottom like this image. if anyone knows about this your small help can make my day. Mainly when I select any option it should show me like this image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use and customize the `BottomNavigationBar` widget with your own requirements. You can have a look at [this blog](https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/how-to-use-flutter-to-build-an-app-with-bottom-navigation).

```
  
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
       title: Text('My Flutter App'),
     ),
     bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
       currentIndex: 0, // this will be set when a new tab is tapped
       items: [
         BottomNavigationBarItem(
           icon: new Icon(Icons.home),
           title: new Text('Home'),
         ),
         BottomNavigationBarItem(
           icon: new Icon(Icons.mail),
           title: new Text('Messages'),
         ),
         BottomNavigationBarItem(
           icon: Icon(Icons.person),
           title: Text('Profile')
         )
       ],
     ),
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: this is not bottom navigation bar

Comment: Then, what is it and what do you have?

Comment: this is a social media app and this is the posting page where users can select the various type of things like image, video. document, etc